# Passing an array of structs where one of the fields is another array, to a function

Tags: arrays, c, memory, memory-management, malloc

This is my struct.

```
    typedef struct {
        uint8_t *data;
        size_t size;
    } buffer;
```

I initialize it like this in my main function.

```
buffer *array;
array = calloc(255, sizeof(*array));
//check for error
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    array[i].data = malloc(sizeof(*array->data));
    //check for error
}
```

Then I pass it to a function.

```
ArrayFunction(&array);
```

This is how it's defined

```
void ArrayFunction(buffer **array) {
    // Doing something to determine somesize
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        array[i]->size = 100;
        array[i]->data = calloc(100, sizeof(uint8_t));
        //check for error
        //Setting the data to something useful
    }
}
```

When looking at my program through a debugger, my initialization in the main function seems fine, memory is valid. Once it enters the ArrayFunction, memory past the 0th element is invalid or uninitialized which causes a segmentation fault at the point of trying to calloc. It does work for the 0th and so does the setting data step.

Comment: This ... `uint8_t *data` ... declares `data` as a *pointer*, not as an array.  It is a pointer no matter what, if anything, its value points to.

Comment: You don't show how the `buffer` variable in `ArrayFunction()` is related to that function's argument.  That is critical.  However, my first guess would be that you want the function to receive a single pointer, not a double pointer, and you want to pass `main`'s `array` itself, not that variable's address.

Comment: You should be able to make it work with the current function signature, too, but that comes back around to how the function is deriving the value of `buffer` from the value of its parameter.

Comment: buffer is the struct. array is the variable in that function. I actually did show everything that I'm doing with it.

Comment: @bugwriter123 are you asking why your code does not compile? The code I guess you have doesn't: https://godbolt.org/z/ne68qnGoW. Or maybe you should [edit] and show a [mcve].

Comment: @bugwriter123, in the future, please *copy & paste* actual code that demonstrates your issue.  Do not retype.  This will avoid confusing us with errors such as the mixup between names `buffer` and `array` in the original version of this question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying too hard. You don't need double pointers.

Explanations in the comments starting with `//**`

You probably just want this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  uint8_t* data;
  size_t size;
} buffer;

void ArrayFunction(buffer *arr) {  //** just pass the buffer (t's a pointer)
  const int somesize = 11;         //** just made up some value

  for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    arr[i].size = somesize;
    arr[i].data = calloc(somesize, sizeof(uint8_t));
        
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  buffer* array;
  array = calloc(255, sizeof(*array));
  //check for error
  for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    array[i].data = malloc(sizeof(*array->data));
    //check for error
  }

  ArrayFunction(array);             //** just pass the pointer
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  I was actually refactoring the code in the same manner, but you were a bit quicker than me.  But you get to the gist of the issue.